# compare 2 date field in django

Tags: django, django-templates

can any body suggest me any idea about how can i compare two date fields in django-admin 
i am the admin and i want to say whenever i update the date of a date field the other date field have to change too(plus 30 days than the first) and if the second date field changed i want to change another field just in django admin page !
thanks in advance

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('P', 'Paid'),
    ('U', 'UNPAID'),
)
class Users(models.Model):
    status              = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES , default="U")
    updated             = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    expiry              = models.DateTimeField(default=updated_plus_30_days())
    # updated_plus_30_days():
        # if updated = "12/8/2017" and expiry is equal to "12/09/2017" and then i changed
        # the updated field to be equal to "12/12/2017" then expiry have to equal to "12/1/2018"
        # if the updated field is >= than expiray then expiray have to increase one month and check
            # if status  is == p:
            #    status = u
            # else :
            #   status = u
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try some thing like this.

```
from datetime import datetime

#pip install python-dateutil
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


class Users(models.Model):
    status              = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES , default="U")
    updated             = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    expiry              = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.expiry = self.updated + relativedelta(days=30)
        super(Users, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you check this one

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
('P', 'Paid'),
('U', 'UNPAID'),
)
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
class Users(models.Model):
    status              = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES , default="U")
    updated             = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    expiry              = models.DateTimeField()
    def save(self):
         self.expiry = default=self.updated+timedelta(days=30)
         super(Users, self).save()
```

Comment: i already tried this but the problem is that i dont want to use datetime.now() cz it's depend on the date that's i am going to choose not just now so if i can do like this expiry              = models.DateTimeField(default=updated+timedelta(days=30)) will solve my problem but unfortunately i can't

Comment: can you try the latest changes